# Can I create an IOS app with access for specific IP only?

Tags: ios

This is for security purpose. Only specific IP can access the app. Is it possible? My idea is to create a login screen with username and password, and the page would also check the IP is specific IP, if the IP doesn't match one in the whitelist then return login error.

Comment: Most likely it is possible, as is pretty much anything. But that probably doesn’t help you much. Please edit the question and ask the actual question you have about this.

Comment: Yes, you could, but changing a device's IP address is trivial.  I presume you aren't going to submit the app for review, in which case how would the person even get the app

Comment: Your app would probably never be approved by Apple for the App Store. You would need to use Enterprise deployment if it's for a company.

Comment: Yes you can and Its possible. Just you need an API settings for App store approval. After App approval from App Store you can go for IP check. Just discuss with your backend team, Backend team can easily handle with Sign in required credentials. [Sign in required - The credential with App Store used to login]